# How to enable syntax highlighting for Markdown inline code with Pandoc?

Tags: markdown, syntax-highlighting, pandoc

The [Pandoc manual](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--no-highlight) says:

> `--no-highlight`
>
> Disables syntax highlighting for code blocks and inlines, even when a language attribute is given.

This sounds like there should be syntax highlighting for inline code. But whenever I use Markdown inline code like

```
This is `print("Hello world")` inline code.
```

there is no syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Okay, should have read a little bit further... found the solution. It's called [Extension: `inline_code_attributes`](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-inline_code_attributes):

> Attributes can be attached to verbatim text, just as with fenced code blocks:
>
> ```
> `<$>`{.haskell}
> ```

So the example above becomes:

```
This is `print("Hello world")`{.python} inline code.
```

Makes sense if you think about it... I'll still leave this up in case someone else has this problem.

Answer (score 4):

Behind the hood, when converting Markdown to PDF, Pandoc use the `\texttt` command for inline code. We can hack the `\texttt` command to add background color for text. Add the following command to `head.tex`:

```tex
\definecolor{bgcolor}{HTML}{E0E0E0}
\let\oldtexttt\texttt

\renewcommand{\texttt}[1]{
  \colorbox{bgcolor}{\oldtexttt{#1}}
}
```

To use `head.tex`, use the `-H` option for pandoc:

```
pandoc --pdf-engine=xelatex -H head.tex test.md -o test.pdf
```

Comment: This is outdated, panda uses thee `\lstinline` command for inline code now - at least that is my experience.

Comment: Are you sure? I have tested on the latest version of Pandoc (version 2.7.3). `\texttt` is still used to render inline code for Markdown. To verify, create a Markdown with only inline code. Then use `pandoc -s -t latex test.md -o test.tex` to produce the intermediate LaTeX file. Check the LaTeX file. What are you seeing, `\lstinline` or `\texttt`?

Comment: My bad, was not using xelatex as my engine.