# How to adjust background colorbox size for inline code in pandoc markdown

Tags: markdown, syntax-highlighting, pandoc

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54669722/11437273) provides a nice way to add background colour to inline code snippets. Using that, my YAML header includes this:

```
header-includes:
 - \usepackage{fvextra}
 - \DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{breaklines,commandchars=\\\{\}}

 - \definecolor{bgcolor}{HTML}{E0E0E0}
 - \let\oldtexttt\texttt

 - \renewcommand{\texttt}[1]{
     \colorbox{bgcolor}{\oldtexttt{#1}}
   }
```

However, the box around the code that contains the background colour seems to take up the whole line and "touches" capital characters in the line below it (in pdf output). How can I adjust the size of that box to take up only some proportion of the line height, for example, max the height of capital letters of the code text?

Comment: This is mostly a LaTeX question: it might get better answers over at https://tex.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I figured the previous, related, one was on SO, but I'll try on tex. Thanks!